# Erro com sintaxe de array jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Não coloquei todo o código para não poluir o texto e a dúvida é quanto a sintaxe abaixo:

Tenho 2 `table html` (tblPerguntas e tblRespostas) e preciso percorrer essas duas tables e enviar para a Controller via Ajax;

```
   var iP = 0;
    var iR = 0;
    var tblPerguntas = $("#tblPerguntas > tbody");
    var tblRespostas = $("#tblRespostas > tbody");

    var Questionario = {
        "Id_Questionario": 1,
        "Nome_Questionario": "Pesquisa Domicilio",
        "Perguntas": []
    };

    tblPerguntas.find("tr").each(function () {
        Questionario.Perguntas.push({
            "Id_Pergunta": 1,
            "Id_Questionario": 1,
            "Pergunta": "Você tem TV a cores?",
            "Respostas": []
        });        
    });

    tblRespostas.find("tr").each(function () {
        Questionario.Perguntas.Respostas.push({
            "Id_Resposta": 1,
            "Resposta": "Sim Tenho 1 geladeira"
        });
    });
```

A dúvida é quanto ao push.

Ocorre esse erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.`

Acredito que sintaxe está errada, se for a sintaxe a forma correta ?

Comment: Você definiu `Questionario.Perguntas` como um *array*, então ele não possui o atributo `Respostas`. O que possui este atributo são os valores de `Questionario.Perguntas`, que poderiam ser acessados pelo índice, `Questionario.Perguntas[0].Respostas`

Comment: Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss ! Seria assim ?: var index = 0;
    tblRespostas.find("tr").each(function () {
        Questionario.Perguntas[index].Respostas.Id_Resposta = 1,
        Questionario.Perguntas[index].Respostas.Resposta = "Sim Tenho 1 geladeira";
  index++;
        });var index = 0;
    tblRespostas.find("tr").each(function () {
        Questionario.Perguntas[index].Respostas.Id_Resposta = 1,
        Questionario.Perguntas[index].Respostas.Resposta = "Sim Tenho 1 geladeira";
  index++;
        });` , não aconteceu nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pegue o primeiro argumento da função do `.each`, que retorna o índice com base `0`, coloque entre colchetes após `Perguntas` do segundo `.each`:

```
tblRespostas.find("tr").each(function (i) {
  Questionario.Perguntas[i].Respostas.push({
      "Id_Resposta": 1,
      "Resposta": "Sim Tenho 1 geladeira"
  });
});
```

Repare que o primeiro argumento da função, representado pela variável `i`, retorna os índices de cada `tr` da tabela.